# Use the header as axis and first column as axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have the following table called totalData, printing totalData will display the following :

```
  Region  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
0 West    1   5.2 3.1 2.05
1 Center  3.1 1.2 1.2 3
2 East    1.9 4.1 1.1 5.3
```

I'd like to use a bar to compare changes through quarters per region and use a 4 bars X section per region to display it .

I'd like to use only the numerical data, and display the region as my X axis and the Quarter as my Y axis.

I've tried to write :

```
totalData.hist(kind='bar')
```

but it ignores the Region and the Quarter and gives me the numerical column as my X axis(how do i get rid of this column?) and integer values until 6 (< than my highest value at the table)

How could I use Region and Quarter as my axis values?

Comment: Are you trying to plot from R or python?

Comment: python , ipython to be exact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really simple. You have two options:

1. Set `Region` as the index of the database
2. pass `x='Region'` to the plot method.

Method 1:

```
from io import StringIO

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas

data = StringIO("""\
Region  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
West    1   5.2 3.1 2.05
Center  3.1 1.2 1.2 3
East    1.9 4.1 1.1 5.3
""")

df = pandas.read_table(data, sep='\s+')
df = df.set_index('Region')
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

Method 2:

```
from io import StringIO

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas

data = StringIO("""\
Region  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
West    1   5.2 3.1 2.05
Center  3.1 1.2 1.2 3
East    1.9 4.1 1.1 5.3
""")

df = pandas.read_table(data, sep='\s+')
df.plot(kind='bar', x='Region')
```

Both give me:

[image]